# System of $4$ equations and $3$ unknowns.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I have to determine when is this system determined, inconsistent and incompatible with variation of $a$ and $b$.

$x+ay+3z=1$

$y+az=0$

$x+y+z=b$

$2x+ay+az=2$

I calculated the determinant of the augmented matrix and it is $a^2 +a -a^2b -ab +6b -6$.

If I factorize it, it would be $(a-2)[(1-b)a+3-3b$

Could I do some conclusions for a and b just using determinant?

Comment: One approach will be solving with a help of Kronecker-Capelli Theorem...

Comment: Thank you for replying. Is there a way to reduce this system in a system of 3 equations? Sorry if I am confusing it, but I have an exam soon

Comment: To @lmnoph: in short NO!

Comment: Just compute the row echelon from.

Comment: In considering $b$ as an unknown we have a system of four equations an four unknowns $(x,y,z,b)$. The determinant is nul for $a=2$ or $a=-3$ One can study these particular cases separetely. If $a\neq 2$ and $a\neq -3$ solving leads to $b=1$ , $x=1$ , $y=0$ , $z=0$. Thus if $b\neq 1$ there is no solution in the case $a\neq 2$ and $a\neq -3$.

Comment: Sorry, a and b are parameters

Comment: You can use the 2nd and 3rd equations to eliminate $y$ and $x$ from the 2 other ones: $y=-az,x=b+(a-1)z.$ You are thus left with $$\begin{cases}(a+1)(2-a)z&=1-b\\(a-1)(2-a)z&=2(1-b),\end{cases}$$ and you can conclude easily.